# How do I use multiple jars in a signed applet?

Tags: java, signed-applet

I have an existing signed applet that, among other things, reads a directory of image files, then loads them and resizes them and uploads them. It has worked great for years but now I need to add Tiff image support. The only way I found to do that is to use the Java Advanced Imaging API. Of course, this means that I have to include the **jai_codec.jar** and **jai_core.jar** files when I deploy the applet. I have modified the archive attribute of my applet element to look something like this:

```
archive="MyApplet.jar?v=123,jai_core.jar,jai_codec.jar"
```

I also signed the 2 additional jar files in the same fashion as I signed the original. However, I still get security warnings and errors and the applet will not run correctly (even if the user attempts to grant permission). What do I need to do to get this working correctly? Am I going to have to extract the contents of the 2 additional jars and put them into one giant jar? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You should only name one archive. The others should be mentioned in the `Class-path:` attribute of the main JAR's manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the applet using a jnlp file. Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html

you can list all the jar you need in the Resources section of the jnlp